# HDD Space used by Browser History

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

I never really clear my browsing history as I often look up at articles that I have read earlier. Today, I came across a post at lifehacker.com that asked how often I clear my browsing history.

So, the question : How to find the amount of space used by browser's history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 and 8 Chrome store the browsing history at:

> C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

In Linux it is stored at:

> /home/$USER/.config/google-chrome/Default

In the default folder, there is a file called `History` which contain the history information. The size of that file is the size of your stored history information. There might also be a file called `Archived History` containing history information that predates the data in `History` as well as per-month history files (e.g., `History Index 2013-11`).

There is, of course, also extra information in a lot of the other files, but these two are the primary ones and it is these two files that usually grow rather big (When we're talking history only).